# why connect in SocketChannel not behaving in non-blocking mode?

Tags: android

I'm trying to open sockets to different host, for that I'm using SocketChannel in non blocking mode:

```
ListIterator iter = hosts.listIterator();
SocketChannel sChannel = null;
while (iter.hasNext()) 
{
    Host host = iter.next();
    sChannel = SocketChannel.open();
    sChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    sChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 80));
}
```

and later I call `finishConnect()` for all.

The problem is `connect()` seems to be blocking.

Comment: The code you posted shows you declaring `sChannel` inside the loop. How could you possibly be calling `finishConnect()` later? (Or using these channels at all)

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same behavior (on android). It seems to arise irrespective of whether the InetSocketAddress is instantiated via...

1. new InetSocketAddress(String host, int port)
2. new InetSocketAddress( InetAddress.getByAddress( byte[] ipAddress ) )
3. new InetSocketAddress( InetAddress.getByAddress( String host, byte[] ipAddress ) )

The stack as I see it is as follows ...

```
InetAddress.gethostbyaddr(byte[]) line: not available [native method]   
InetAddress.getHostByAddrImpl(byte[]) line: 558 
Inet4Address(InetAddress).getHostName() line: 352   
SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketAddress) line: 259  
ScannerTargetAuxillaryTest.runBusinessUseCase(InetSocketAddress[]) line: 38 
ScannerTargetAuxillaryTest.testVersion2() line: 125 
ScannerTargetAuxillaryTest.main() line: 247 
TestActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 46  
Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1047   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2466  
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2519   
ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 123 
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1870  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4370    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```